# almacenar varios array en LocalStorage Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Estoy almacenando datos de un formulario en el localstorage, mi idea es hacer una lista de cada vez que se envie ese formulario, se guarde en un array todos sus datos.
Logro hacerlo, peero lo q me esta pasando es que cada vez que envio la informacion al localstorage, se me reescribe la anterior.

```
        var datosDeCadaEquipoRecuperado = 
 
       [estado,hdmi,av,fuente,control,accesorios,
      idLocalEquipo,terminal,identificacion];

           localStorage.setItem('transito', 
        JSON.stringify(datosDeCadaEquipoRecuperado));
```

y cada vez que ejecuto el formulario se guarda la informacion correctamente, pero no persiste la anterior

pude enviar todos los datos al localstorage sin reescribir con esta funcion que encontre. la comparto para el que le sirva. Si tienen otro metodo, seria bueno que aporten.

```
        function 
         SaveDataToLocalStorage(estado,hdmi,av,fuente,
         control,accesorios,idLocalEquipo,terminal,identificacion)
        {
       var a = [];
   //   Analizar los datos serializados nuevamente en una serie de objetos
       a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transito')) || [];
   //  envio los nuevos datos (ya sea un objeto o cualquier otra cosa) en la 
     matriz
     a.push(estado,hdmi,av,fuente,control,
     accesorios,idLocalEquipo,terminal,identificacion);
   //  Alerta al valor de la matriz
     alert(a); 
    //  tiene que ser un objeto [matriz de objetos]
      //   Vuelva a serializar la matriz de nuevo en una cadena y guárdela en 
     localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('transito', JSON.stringify(a));

     var DataDelLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));
    console.log(localstorage);
     }
```

Comment: tienes que capturarlo convertirlo en array y luego almacenarlos

Comment: entiendo, pero tendria que definir la cantidad de veces que puedo capturar un formulario? . ejem= var captura1, var captura2, captura3, y asi. Porque puedo enviar hasta 30 veces el formulario.

Comment: es mejor que `localStorage.setItem('transito', JSON.stringify( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transito')).push(datosDeCadaEquipoRecuperado)))`

Comment: jack la estoy probando, el push me sale que es null, en lo que lo tenga, te digo que tal

Comment: No pude hacerlo asi bro.   Consegui este metodo function SaveDataToLocalStorage(estado,hdmi,av,fuente,control,accesorios,idLocalEquipo,terminal,identificacion)
 {
     var a = [];
     a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('transito')) || [];
      a.push(estado,hdmi,av,fuente,control,accesorios,idLocalEquipo,terminal,identificacion);
  
      alert(a); 
  
     localStorage.setItem('transito', JSON.stringify(a));

      var DataDelLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));
     console.log(localstorage);

 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que añadir los nuevos datos a los anteriores:

```javascript
var datosDeCadaEquipoRecuperado = [1, 2, 3]; // los datos que sean

// localStorage.getItem() devuelve null si la clave no existe
var datos_existentes = localStorage.getItem('transito');
datos_existentes = datos_existentes === null ? [] : JSON.parse(datos_existentes);

datos_existentes.push(datosDeCadaEquipoRecuperado);
// o
// datos_existentes.push({tiempo: new Date().getTime(), datos: datosDeCadaEquipoRecuperado});

localStorage.setItem('transito', JSON.stringify(datos_existentes));
```

Comment: es mas optimo tu metodo. Gracias jotaelesalinas

Comment: De hecho, creo que no es necesario "jsonizar" los datos, pero no estoy seguro.

Comment: ahi voy viendo despues como lo manejo, eso despues tengo que hacer un insert por cada array. Asi como esta me parece que me sirve.